# Getting newest 2 values per group of rows SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

So I have combed through multiple pages of stackoverflow questions and it seems like I keep getting close but dont get the exact results I need...so I have succumbed to submitting this question.

To start off this is on a SQL Server 2000 server...which sucks, I know.

I have 2 tables linking together in a sql query that is overall fairly basic. Sample data is listed below:
[image: Current Results]

The query I use to get that data is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AH.locationid as locationid
,AH.adate as date
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '201' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib1
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '204' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib2
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '206' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib3
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '212' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib4
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '215' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib5
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '218' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib6
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '221' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib7
,Min( CASE WHEN Asum.code = '231' THEN Amount END ) AS attrib8
,AH.checkid as checktype
FROM [asum] ASum

INNER JOIN [Ahead] AH
ON  Asum.AID = AH.AID

WHERE AH.code IN ('212','201','206','204','215','218','221','231')

AND AH.checkid <> 'c'
AND AH.checkid <> 'b'

GROUP BY 
 AH.code
,ASum.amount
,AH.adate
,AH.checkid

ORDER BY 
 AH.locationid
,AH.adate
,attrib1
,attrib2
,attrib3
,attrib4
,attrib5
,attrib6
,attrib7
,attrib8
,AH.checkid'
```

So what I am trying to do is return the newest two dates for every location  and all of the attrib for those newest two dates.

So I am essentially trying to get something that looks like this:
[image: Wanted Results]

The closest I have gotten is doing adding the below inner join code to the query and that gets me just the top date...the problem I face is how to get two max dates from this subquery that I innerjoin too.

```
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                locationid,
                MAX(adate) as newest

             FROM   ahead

             GROUP BY locationid) t1
 ON t1.locationid = AH.locationid
 AND t1.newest = AH.adate
```

So with that inner join I just get 1 of each location id instead of two of each location id like I need. The rough part is that this is on a SQL Server 2000 database...UGH.

Thanks so much in advance for any tips/advice!

Comment: Update to a supported version of SQL Server.  SQL Server 2000 has had no support for *years*.  Using an unsupported commercial product seems dangerous for most applications.

Comment: Yea...I know. Legacy stuff that is in the process of getting moved off but this is part of the process of moving away from it.

Comment: Usually, the selected columns which are not argument to aggregate functions (e.g. MIN) are the same as those listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jarlh, that's more than a "usually". SQL requires that the select list of an aggregate query reference only the grouping columns and functions of the groups.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you don't have to select grouped columns. (Happens once in a while...)

Comment: @jarlh, if you attempt to select columns that are not grouping columns (as opposed to aggregate functions involving those columns) then your query is not valid SQL.  What would it even mean?  A few implementations support it anyway -- MySQL in particular comes to mind -- but that doesn't make it valid SQL.

Comment: @Zi0n1, can there be duplicates of (locationid, date)?

Comment: John,

There cannot be duplicates of location id with the same exact time. So for example you will never see locationid 1001 have the date of 1999-09-01 12:00:00 twice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I said the opposite, i.e. you don't have to select a column even if it is in the GROUP BY. (Can sometimes make sense...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test it, because I don't have SQL Server 2000, but I think this might work:

```
 INNER JOIN (SELECT a1.locationid,
                    MAX(a1.adate) as newest,
                    MAX(a2.adate) as second_newest
               FROM ahead a1
               JOIN ahead a2
                 ON a2.locationid = a1.locationid
                AND a2.adate < a1.adate
              GROUP BY a1.locationid) t1
ON t1.locationid = AH.locationid
AND (t1.newest = AH.adate OR t1.second_newest = AH.adate)
```

**EDIT**: Looking at John Bollinger's comment, I should add that I only expect this to work if the `(locationid, adate)` combination is unique.

Comment: You are spot on man! THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Such a frustrating problem to face on a Friday morning haha.

Comment: Would you potentially know how to do this except it also pull individual rows and not just locations with 2 dates associated with it but locations with only 1 date associated with it as well? Ran into an issue where the query only pulls locations with 2 dates and leaves the locations with a single date out.

Comment: I'm thinking that if you change `JOIN ahead a2` to a left join instead, `LEFT JOIN ahead a2`,, it would take care of that edge case.

Comment: Yea that is what I figured but unfortunately the left join doesnt work. I think it is because of the condition for the less then. I have been trying to work out a case statement but havent been successfull thusfar.

Comment: I don't see how the "less than" would cause an issue. In fact, the more I think about it, I really think that the left join should have done the trick.  If you take the time to set up and post a link to a SQLFiddle that reproduces a simplified version of your problem, I'm sure we can figure it out.

Comment: Well I loaded an example into SQL fiddle and as I looked at it more closely I saw my issue. I included a where clause in the subquery which didnt allow an option for a2 to be null so it didnt return a value. I added an OR part to the where clause and its working perfectly. Thanks again for all the help!